# If x~Poisson(9), compute P(x=0.8)

Tags: statistics

I would think to solve it as:

(e^-9)(9^.8)/(.8!)

But obviously .8! is not correct so I have no idea what to do

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe it is a trick question. Poisson takes only integer values 0, 1, 2, .... So P(X = 0.8) = 0.

Answer (score 0):

It should be $P(x=9) = \dfrac{e^{-\mu}\cdot \mu^{k}}{k!}=\dfrac{e^{-0.8}\cdot 0.8^{9}}{9!}$

Comment: That number is unreasonably small and doesn't make sense

Comment: Yes, I think so but it looks like your problem statement is incorrect to begin with......

Comment: That is exactly my homework question... I don't understand it either

Comment: To be clear, you have changed the problem to $X \sim Pois(\mu = 0.8)$ and then asking for $P(X = 9).$ A reasonable speculation, but certainly not the original question.